# What is the use of "Maintain a current best estimate" of location Android?

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location, locationlistener, location-provider

I've read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328260/where-do-the-location-and-currentbestlocation-come-from-in-android-dev-guide-o).

What I don't understand is why this function `isBetterLocation()` even exists. The function tells the difference between "current location fix" and "new location". But what are those 2 locations really?

I can think of

- Last location stored in application preferences, database etc. and location retrieved from location provider e.g. GPS
- Location retrieved from location provider and latest location gotten through `onLocationChanged()`

In either case, the latter is more up-to-date; therefore, more accurate. So, why bother making comparison at all?
The only explanation I can think of is that more up-to-date location information isn't always more accurate. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html, there is an explanation on this page (android documentation)

Comment: Thanks @Quanturium, as mentioned above, I've already read such documentation but it doesn't answer my question